# DataGridAutoFilter C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Существует библиотека DataGridAutoFilter для winforms, которая вешает фильтр на столбец в datagridview. Я обновляю datagridview так :

```
        public void update_shift()
    {
        cn.Open();
        BindingSource bsshift = new BindingSource();
        DataSet dsshift = new DataSet();
        DataTable dtshift = new DataTable();

        dsshift.Tables.Add(dtshift);

        SqlDataAdapter dashift = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dashift = new SqlDataAdapter("select shift.truck, shift.tripNumber, case when exists(select * from shift sh1 WHERE cast(sh1.capacityKg as int) < (select sum(cast(kg as int)) from orders join action on orders.order_number = action.id_order where action.shiftcode = sh1.shiftcode) and sh1.shiftcode = shift.shiftcode) THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as ErrUpload, shift.comment, case when exists (SELECT * FROM action WHERE shiftcode = shift.shiftcode and id_order is not null) THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as planned, shift.datework,driver, statusName, trailer,subcontractor.contactName, shift.shiftcode, shift.capacityKg, shift.capacityPal, (select sum(cast(kg as int)) from orders join action on orders.order_number = action.id_order where action.shiftcode = shift.shiftcode)  as uploadKg,(select sum(cast(pal as int)) from orders join action on orders.order_number = action.id_order where action.shiftcode = shift.shiftcode)  as uploadPal, (select top 1 address.cityName from address join action on address.addressCode = action.finish where action.shiftcode = shift.shiftcode) as firstCity from shift  left join dbo.subcontractor ON shift.subcontractor = dbo.subcontractor.contact_externalId left join shiftStatus ON shift.status = shiftStatus.id_status WHERE shift.datework ='2016-06-17'  ORDER by shift.truck, shift.tripNumber ASC", cn);
        dashift.Fill(dtshift);
        bsshift.DataSource = dtshift;
        int index2 = dataGridView2.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = bsshift;
        cn.Close();

    }
```

И фильтр со столбцов сбивается, становится все с нуля. То есть, выбрали на фильтре фамилию Петров, правой кнопкой мыши вызвал еще одно окно с данными "Петрова", изменил ему, к примеру возраст. По закрытию формы 2(с данными) у меня стоит запуск функции в первой форме `update_shift()`, что бы на первой форме в строке сразу обновились данные, в этом случае по фамилии петров, но после обновления слетает фильтр со столбца и приходится снова его ставить.

Если делать вот так

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.newDataSet1.DataTable1);
    }
```

То не слетает, объясните пожалуйста, в чем разница, и как мне решить эту проблему? Лепить кучу комбо боксов над datagridview не красиво.

Comment: Посмотрите может [DataGridViewWithFilter](https://github.com/DartAlex/DataGridViewWithFilter) подойдёт?

Comment: Штука в том, что надо запоминать фильтры до обновления и применять после, а так же учитывать что появилось нового после обновления.

Comment: @DartAlex, это я понимаю, но почему во втором случае все в порядке? Я понимаю что нужно учесть при следующем обновление на каком столбце и что именно было выбрано на фильтре, но я не знаю как это реализовать, так как на каком столбце и что выбрано получить в этой библиотеке нельзя.

Comment: @DartAlex попробовал то что вы дали, ситуация такая же, после вызова этой функции `update_shift()` фильтр слетает.

Comment: Фильтуется на самом деле не `DataGridView`, а `DataSet`. Во втором случае вы не меняете `DataSet`, а обновляете старый. В первом же `DataSet` новый. Это к вопросу почему слетает фильтр.

Comment: На перед обновленимем сохранить `string StrFilter = (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter;` А после обновления `(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = StrFilter;` Но нужно проверить.

Comment: Сработало. проверил...

Comment: @DartAlex вы на библиотеке что мне скинули пробуете или DataGridAutoFilter? Я пробую на DataGridAutoFilter не пашет, хотя я так понимаю они почти одинаковые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо сохранить фильтры перед обновлением `DataGridView`, так как фильтрация происходит не на уровне `DataGridView`, а на уровне `DataSet`. А при назначении `DataGridView` нового `DataSet` со старым теряются и фильтры.

```
string filter = "";

// Ошибка если фильтров нет
try
{
   filter = (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter;
}
catch { }

dataGridView1.DataSource = bsshift;

if (filter.Length > 0)
{
   (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
}
```

Comment: Как только не крутил, все равно не пашет... Завтра видео сниму кину ссылку может Вы меня не так поняли.

Comment: @Winteriscoming, откуда брали DataGridAutoFilter?

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало, когда из функции вынес  BindingSource bsshift = new BindingSource(); в общую часть.